# How do I change the function to display values ​calculated based on the previous item?

Tags: c#

I have this class

```
public class MonthlyPayment
    {
        public int Luna { get; set; }
        public double SoldInitial { get; set; }
        public double PlataLunara { get; set; }
        public double Dobanda { get; set; }
        public double Principal { get; set; }
        public double Asigurare { get; set; }
        public double Comision { get; set; }
        public double TotalLunar { get; set; }
        public double CreditBalance { get; set; }
    }
```

And this data context

```
public class CreditDataContext
    {
        public List<MonthlyPayment> MonthlyPayments { get; set; }
        public void LoadMonthlyPayments()
        {
            MonthlyPayments = new List<MonthlyPayment>();
            MonthlyPayment payment = null;
            payment = new MonthlyPayment()
            {
                Luna = 0,
                SoldInitial = 0.00,
                PlataLunara = 0.00,
                Dobanda = 0.00,
                Principal = 0.00,
                Asigurare = 0.00,
                Comision = 200.00,
                TotalLunar = 200.00,
                CreditBalance = 10000.00f,
            };
            MonthlyPayments.Add(payment);
            for(int i=1;i<=12;i++)
            {
                MonthlyPayments.Add(InitializeMyObject(i));
                    }
        }
       public MonthlyPayment InitializeMyObject(int i)
        {
            MonthlyPayment x = new MonthlyPayment();
            x.Luna = i;
            x.SoldInitial = 10000;
            x.Dobanda = ((9.75 / 100) / 12) * x.CreditBalance;
            double v = 1 + x.Dobanda;
            x.PlataLunara = (x.CreditBalance * x.Dobanda) / (1 - Math.Pow(v, -12));
            x.Principal = x.PlataLunara - x.Dobanda;
            x.Asigurare = (0.10 / 100) * x.CreditBalance;
            x.Comision = (0.04 / 100) * x.SoldInitial;
            x.TotalLunar = x.Dobanda + x.Asigurare + x.PlataLunara;
            x.CreditBalance = x.SoldInitial - x.PlataLunara;
            return x;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that displays the same value for each item in the list.
How do I change the function to display values ​​calculated based on the previous item?
For example , to calculate 'Dobanda(interest)' for month 2, use the credit balance from month 1.

Comment: use the credit balance from month 1. what do you mean. can you write a sample for month 2. i will try to integrate into code.

Comment: I don't see any thing called credit balance in the code. i don't know the domain. so just write the calculation for second month. in English i will convert it to code.

Comment: 1th month credit balance = 100000  ,                                                                               
 for 2nd month interest=(9.75 / 100) / 12) * 1th monthcredit balance,                               for 2nd month credit balance=9203                                                                               for 3rd month interest=(9.75 / 100) / 12) * 2nd month balance,                                                 .................................................................................................

Comment: credit balance you mean SoldInitial ?

Comment: I edit now the code with CreditBalance